# What is lm_svd_feasible algorithm in Octave optim package?

Tags: optimization, octave, least-squares

I am using lsqcurvefit function from optim package in Octave for non-linear LSQ optimization. In documentation of function its written, only 'lm_svd_feasible' back-end algorithm is available. Which algorithm is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is described in the manual of the optim package. If you type `optim_doc` at the Octave prompt (with the optim package loaded), you get the optim manual where that algorithm is described. To search on the manual, type `s` or `/`. Note that `Regexp search []:` appears at the bottom of the window. Type `lm_svd_feasible` and then enter. The first result will be in the menu:

```
Optimization backends
* lm_svd_feasible::            L/M algorithm with SVD, constraints met
                                 throughout optimization.
```

That is actually a link. Since your cursor will already be above `lm_svd_feasible`, press enter again which will take you to the section "Default backend lm_svd_feasible of residual minimization".

Octave and Octave Forge packages use the info format, so see the [info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html) for instructions.  Alternatively, the manual is also [online in HTML](https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/package_doc/index.html)